# PreparedStatement and Array in c++

Tags: c++, mysql

This is how I define an array

```
  const int MAXMATCH = 10;
  string A[MAXMATCH] = {"g111", "g112", "g113"};
```

With the code below I intend to use the array in the query

```
  con->setClientOption("libmysql_debug", "d:t:O,/tmp/mysql.trace");
  string A[MAXMATCH] = {"g111", "g112", "g113"};
  pstmt = con->prepareStatement("SELECT lenght FROM rods WHERE name = ? ");
    for (int i = 0; i < MAXMATCH; i++)
    {
      string lastmatch = A[i];
      pstmt->setString(1, lastmatch);        
      res = pstmt->executeQuery();   
      con->setClientOption("client_trace", &on_off); 
      res->afterLast();   
      while (res->previous())         
      cout << "\t... Lenght ...: " << res->getInt("lenght") << endl;
      delete res;
    }
```

The code compiles, but I do not get any result. There must be something wrong passing from the array to setstring, but I do not understand what the problem is.

Comment: Is your column spelled correctly ("lenght")?

Comment: And, which connector are you using? Is this MySQL Connector/C++? Then you can enable tracing and debugging output, see http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/connector-cpp-debug-tracing.html

Comment: Andreas, yes lenght is spelled ok and yes I'm using MySQl Connector/c+; I'll have a go with tracing....

Comment: I modified the code for tracing the output, it compiles but I do not find /tmp/mysql.trace. I also built the connector with "cmake -DMYSQLCPPCONN_TRACE_ENABLE:BOOL=1".

Comment: Does the string in the prepared statement need to be bounded by '' marks? IE "...where name = '?'"

Comment: I solved the problem putting the while inside the for loop. It was quite a big mistake.... Thanks.

Comment: ethrbunny, in that way it did not work for me.